# Defining a jQuery ajax callback parameter as an existing object type

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, callback

I admit this question is getting to the limits of what I know of JavaScript & jQuery, and there is probably a more proper way to state my question (which would help in finding an existing solution), but if you can bear with me, this is what I'm after.

I have an existing object class I've defined. I'm making a jQuery ajax call using getJSON, and I want my callback parameter (which is an object) to be classed as my custom object, so that I can access that class' methods from it.

So I have some object class

```
function Boo() {

  this.param1;
  this.param2;

  this.yah = function() {
     ...
  }

}
```

and then I have something elsewhere of the sort

```
$.getJSON(url,function(new_instance) {
   //from my php source this passed object is already loaded with param1, param2...
   alert(new_instance.param1);    //no probs
   //but i want to be able to then call
   new_instance.yah();
});
```

In other words, I want new_instance to be considered an instance of Boo(). I know in stuff like ActionScript you have to class the incoming parameters for exactly this reason, dunno what flexibility I have in JS.

I thought maybe about having an intermediate function that takes in the incoming object and creates/populates a new instance of Boo() but not sure if there is a more clever method.

Many thanks!!

Comment: To both responses so far, yes I know I should be prototyping (;D), you may assume that my final product will be more efficiently written...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not define methods in the constructor function, you are 
defining them over and over again every time the costructor 
is called. Move them over to the prototype:

```
Boo.prototype = {

    yah: function() {

    },

    bah: function() {

    }

    ...

};
```

a little helper function:

```
function coerceTo( proto, values ) {
    var r = Object.create( proto );
    for( var key in values ) {
        r[key] = values[key];
    }

    return r;
}
```

Depending on browser, `Object.create` might not be available, so:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            throw new Error('Object.create implementation only accepts the first parameter.');
        }
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
new_instance = coerceTo( Boo.prototype, new_instance );

new_instance instanceof Boo //true
new_instance.yah();
```

Comment: Here's what I did, it isn't properly prototyped but the general idea is there...

    <code>Boo.prototype.dp(params,callback) {
      $.getJSON(params,function(r){
         if (typeof(r) == 'object') {
             //this line i realize can be written better as above
             var t = new Boo();
             //loop and load up params here (not shown)
             callback(t);
          } else {
             callback(r);
          }
     });


     another_instance.dp(params,function(new_instance) { new_instance.yah(); //hooray! } );</code>

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(newObjData) {
   var newObj = $.extend(new Boo(), newObjData);
   newObj.yah();
});
```

Also consider moving your `Boo` methods to object `prototype` so the methods don't get recreated for each `Boo` instance:

```
var Boo = function() {
    this.param1;
    this.param2;
}

Boo.prototype.yah = function() {
    console.log(this.param1);
}
```

Comment: Calling the original constructor like this can cause side effects or errors.

Comment: OK many thanks for both answers, this one looks ideally low-budget, granted as I'm building an API I was hoping to be extra fussy and somehow let the users just use myfunction(params,function(boo){ .. } and use 'boo' as a Boo() right away in their scripts, but probably asking too much!

Comment: All depends on your needs. But I should admit that the answer of @Esailija is conceptually correct and more robust.